# Batch calculate the euclidean distance between a given array and the arrays of the mongodb database

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

**What I'm trying to do:**

Calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between a given array ([0,1.2,0,1.5,0,0.3,1,2,1] for example) and all the other arrays inside the objects of a collection with the structure below:

{'myname':'001','myarray':[0,1,2.0,1,0,0.3,1,2,1]}

**How I am creating the collection**:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mydata = [{'myname':'001',
          'myarray':[0,1,2.0,1,0,0.3,1,2,1]},
          {'myname':'002',
          'myarray':[0,0,0,1,1,0.7,1,2,1]},
          {'myname':'003',
          'myarray':[0,1,2,1.2,1,2,1,2,1]},
          {'myname':'004',
          'myarray':[0,0,2,0,0,0,1.3,2,1]},
          {'myname':'005',
          'myarray':[0,1,0.5,1,0,0,1,2,1]},
          ]


client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['mydb']
collection = db['mydata']

for data in mydata:
    collection.insert_one(data)
```

**What I found on the other solutions**:

I saw many examples of how to calculate a geospatial distance using MongoDB, but unfortunately, it looks like it only works with a 2-elements arrays (as in [longitude, latitude]). In these cases, people are using `$near` and `$geoNear`.
I also found something about map-reduce functions which should be useful for this situation, but I'm new on MongoDB and I don't have an idea of how can I create and execute a function through collections.

**What would be great to have**:

A Python code using the code example above for return a list of each object with its distance to the given array like:
{'myname':'001','mydistance': 15.}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [map-reduce syntax in pymongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.0/examples/map_reduce.html), we need map and reduce JS functions passed in as strings. To specify the point wrt. which we'll calculate the distance, we need to pass in an additional variable (`target`) into the function scope. In sum, the operation looks something like this:

```
from bson.code import Code

map = Code("function () {....")
reduce = Code("function (key, values) {...")

point_array = collection.find({ 'myname': '005' }, { 'myarray': 1 })[0]['myarray']
result = collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, "myresults", scope={"target": point_array})
```

There are probably a million ways to split up the map-reduce functions, but here's how I've done it. First, we have the map function, which emits a bunch of element-wise differences between one array and your "target" array, along with a key. I've gone ahead and assumed that `myname` is unique, so I've used that as the key:

```
# map
function () {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < this.myarray.length; i++) {
    emit(this.myname, this.myarray[i] - target[i]);
  }
}
```

Then, to get our final distance, the reduce function takes the differences emitted from the map step, sums their squares, then takes the squareroot of that sum, according to the formula:

```
# reduce
function (key, values) {
  var total = 0;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    total = total + Math.pow(values[i],2);
  }
  return Math.sqrt(total);
}
```

The output of result is then:

```
{'_id': '001', 'value': 1.5297058540778354}
{'_id': '002', 'value': 1.6552945357246849}
{'_id': '003', 'value': 2.7}
{'_id': '004', 'value': 2.083266665599966}
{'_id': '005', 'value': 0.0}
```

Comment: GREAT! Thank you very much!

Comment: Look... There is a missing bracket on the last line of the first code cell. I tried to correct that, but I can't edit only a single character.